# Protractor e2e test written in typescript with page object

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to write some e2e tests in typescript using Protractor and Jasmine syntax using a Page Object to abstract the DOM structure from the tests.

When running protractor I get an error telling me that my my page object is not a function.

Here is the page object as a typescript class: `home.po.spec.ts`

```
module Tests.e2e.Home {
    export class HomePage {
        emailInput;

        constructor() {
            this.emailInput = element(by.model('email'));
        }

        get(): void {
            browser.get('https://localhost:44300');
        }

        get email(): string {
            return this.emailInput.getText();
        }

        set email(value: string) {
            this.emailInput.sendKeys(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test: `home.e2e.spec.ts`

```
///<reference path="home.po.spec.ts"/>
module Tests.e2e.Home {
    describe('home view', () => {
        it('should mark invalid email in field', () => {
            // arrange
            var homePage = new HomePage();
            homePage.get();
            var emailField = homePage.emailInput;

            // act
            homePage.email = 'some invalid email';

            // assert
            expect(emailField.getAttribute('class')).toMatch('ng-invalid');
        });
    });
}
```

I'm writing the tests in Visual Studio 2013 and running protractor with a gulp task on nodejs.

Here is the error message:

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.5.153:23704/wd/hub
F

Failures:

1) home view should mark invalid email in field
Message:
TypeError: Home.HomePage is not a function
    Stacktrace:
    TypeError: Home.HomePage is not a function
    at [object Object].<anonymous>(C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\app\Prese
    ntation.Web\Tests\home.e2e.spec.ts:5:28)
at C: \Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jas
minewd\index.js:94:14
at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue(C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
    dules\protractor\node_modules\selenium - webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
at[object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
at[object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async - callback.js:45:37)
at[object Object].jasmine.Block.execute(C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
    ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine - 1.3.1.js:1174:17
    )
at[object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_(C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
    e_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine - 1.3.1.js:2209:31)
at[object Object]._onTimeout(C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
    \protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine - 1.3.1.js:2199:18)
Error
at[object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\app\Prese
ntation.Web\Tests\home.e2e.spec.ts:3:9)
at[object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_(C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
    ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine - 1.3.1.js:913:21)

at[object Object].jasmine.Env.describe(C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
    de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine - 1.3.1.js:898:15)
at describe (C:\Users\BSO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_m
    odules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine - 1.3.1.js:658:27)
at e2e.Home.e2e.Home(C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\app\Presentation.We
    b\Tests\home.e2e.spec.ts:2:5)
at Tests.e2e.Tests.e2e(C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\app\Presentation.
    Web\Tests\home.e2e.spec.ts:16:2)
at Tests (C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\app\Presentation.Web\Tests\home
    .e2e.spec.ts:16:2)
at Object.<anonymous>(C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\app\Presentation.W
    eb\Tests\home.e2e.spec.ts:16:2)

Finished in 0.031 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

Shutting down selenium standalone server.
    [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Can anyone help me with this? How can I make the test file reference

### Solution

The solution is to not use internal modules in TypeScript for this.
By changing to commonjs module system and use typescripts `import something = require('path to someting')` it works as expected.

Here is a sample of the setup.
The page object `home.po.spec.ts`:

```
class HomePage {

    getPage(): void {
        browser.get('https://localhost:44300/');
    }

    nameElement = element(by.id('name'));
    get nameInput(): string {
        var value: string;
        this.nameElement.getAttribute('value').then(v => value = v);
        return value;
    }

    set nameInput(value: string) {
        this.nameElement.sendKeys(value);
    }
}

export = HomePage;
```

And the test spec `home.e2e.spec.ts`:

```
import HomePo = require('./home.po.spec');

describe('home view', () => {
    it('name input should be writeable', () => {
        // arrange
        var pageObject: HomePo = new ItProjectEditPo();
        pageObject.getPage();

        // act
        pageObject.nameInput = 'SomeName';

        // assert
        expect(pageObject.nameInput).toBe('SomeName');
    });
});
```

Some notes on the solution.
The page object needs to resolve the element getAttribute promise when using TypeScript properties, getAttribute returns a promise but sendKeys takes a string.

[TypeScript modules documentation is here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules). It took me some time to understand it, but it makes good sense now. By using this module structure it is also possible to import nodejs packages.

Comment: In `home.e2e.spec.ts`, don't you need something along the lines of `import {HomePage} from './home.po.spec';`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably told protractor to include all your `*.spec.ts` files, so protractor will include them by the order of the abc. This means that the file `home.e2e.spec.ts` will be included before the `home.po.spec.ts` file.

You have two options:

1. Change the order of the files (Bad idea).
2. Tell TypeScript to export into commonjs module format, so it will be possible to do `import` to the page object (Instead of reference files)

There's another issue that you didn't see: You initialized the `emailInput` in the constructor but called `get` after it was initialized...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm currently having a lot of things around my head, so I will get back to this. Some of my other problems with the setup are also resolved with the commonjs module format, so this will probably be the solution. I return when I have time to test it.